# How to call a method in a different Java File?

Tags: java

So I'm pretty new to Java and following a course to learn some coding. Now for this course, I've got a book with theory and exercises. Now I'm stuck at a certain exercise but the book doesn't provided theory or answers to this exercise.

So I've got this Class file (`DateFirstTry.java`) and a Main file, which runs the program.

```
public class DateFirstTry {

    public String month;
    public int day;
    public int year;
    
    public void writeOutput()
    {
        System.out.println(month + " " + day + ", " + year);
    }
    
    public void makeItNewYears()
    {
        month = "January";
        day = 1;
    }
   
    public void yellIfNewYears()
    {
        if ( (month.equalsIgnoreCase("January") ) && (day == 1) ) 
            System.out.println("Hurrah!");
        else 
            System.out.println("Not New Year's Day.");
    }
}
```

```
public class DateFirstTryDemo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DateFirstTry date1, date2;
        date1 = new DateFirstTry();
        date2 = new DateFirstTry();
        date1.month = "December";
        date1.day = 31;
        date1.year = 2012;
        System.out.println("date1:");
        date1.writeOutput();
    
        date2.month = "July";
        date2.day = 4;
        date2.year = 1776;
        System.out.println("date2:");
        date2.writeOutput();
    
        DateFirstTry makeItNewYears;
    
        DateFirstTry yellIfNewYears;
}
```

So, they explained how I should create the `makeItNewYears` and `yellIfNewYears` methods, but don't explain how to call them in the main code. I've tried somethings and `DateFirstTry makeItNewYears;` is the only thing that doesn't give an error, but also doesn't give any output.

I hope someone can help me with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since these are instance methods, you first need to create an instance of `DateFirstTry`, like e.g., you did with `date1`:

```java
DateFirstTry someDate = new DateFirstTry();
```

You can then call methods on this instance using the `.` syntax, followed by the method's name, and parentheses (`()`) containing the arguments you want to pass to the method (in this case - none):

```java
someDate.makeItNewYears();
someDate.yellIfNewYears();
```

Comment: Alright, that helped a lot! So, for example, how can I change the month or day to the one in the makeItNewYears method?

Comment: @DamianEickhoff you can use the `.` operator to refer to data members too, as you did in the `main` you shared: `someDate.day = 1`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. In the Method "makeItNewYears" I already gave up a month and day. But, if I try ```date1.day = date1.makeItNewYears.month();``` it won't accept it.

It works fine if I change the day and month in the main, but I want to use the method to change those 2 variables.

Comment: @DamianEickhoff `makeItNewYears` updates the members of the `DateFirstTry` it's called on. If you want a way to get the day of new year's, you'll have to extract a method (or a constant) that returns it

Comment: Ah, right. I got it now. If I run ```date1.makeItNewYears();``` first and then ```date1.writeOutput();``` it gives me 1 january, even if the date and month in the main are set to somehting different.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

A class can have a state and behavior. State is data. In your class `DateFirstTry`, these are the variables contributing to the state:

```
    public String month;
    public int day;
    public int year;
```

Methods represent a specific behavior or a set of operations. The behavior of the class performs action on the data. It may or may not change the state of the class while performing these actions.
For instance,

```
public void makeItNewYears()
{
    month = "January";
    day = 1;
}
```

the method `makeItNewYears()` changes the state, since it changes the value of `month` and `day`. On the other hand,

```
public void writeOutput()
{
    System.out.println(month + " " + day + ", " + year);
}
```

the method does some action but does not change state. It just uses the data but does not change its value.

An object is an instance of this class. If `Person` is a class, then `John` is an instance of this class. A class can have any number of instances. Every instance has its own state and all the behavior defined in the class.
To create an instance, you use the following syntax:

```
DateFirstTry date1 = new DateFirstTry();
DateFirstTry date2 = new DateFirstTry();
```

`date1` and `date2` are two instances/objects of this class. They have the same properties `month`, `day` and `year`. But their values can be different for each object.
For calling a method, you need to call it on an instance. We have two instances `date1` and `date2`. For calling `writeOutput()` use:

```
date1.writeOutput()
```

You can call the same method on `date2` as well, it will perform the operation on its data.

Each object is able to perform this behavior.

```
date1.yellIfNewYears()
```

will check if the values of month, day and year of `date1` is New Years. If you call the same method as:

```
date2.yellIfNewYears()
```

it will perform this operation with the month, date and year value in `date2`.